# Overlay a fullscreen Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, web-application, overlay

What are the options to overlay a Remote Desktop Connection?

The connection is in fullscreen mode. So the taskbar of the host system is no longer visible.

A Brwoser on the host system runs a web application that sends notifications via the Notification API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification).

These notifications should also be visible to the user during the work on the remote desktop system.

On a dual monitor system they are actually over the remote desktop connection. For a single-monitor system, the RDC window is not superimposed.

Running the remote desktop connection only in window mode would only be the last resort.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: If you hit `Windows Key + Up Arrow` you will make the window fit the screen without officially putting it into "Full Screen mode".  I know you would rather not have it windowed, but would that work?

Comment: In this particular case it is difficult because the RDC configuration can not be changed. So the user would have to do the necessary steps every morning. Didn't found a Cross Browser solution yet. But the Edge Browser uses the Windows 10 system notifications for Notification Api. And these notifications overlay the Fullscreen RDC window even on a single-monitor system.